Ubuntu 24.04 is failing after attempting to download Steam games to external SSD
I just got a new Samsung SSD. I wanted to boot with Ubuntu and play Steam games on it, but I am having issues.
When downloading games on Steam, the download proceeds fine for a while (most attempts have been 5-10 GB, some none), but then I experience the Steam interface closing, and all my apps are not able to open. I get the error "program 'env' not found in $PATH". This forces me to restart the system, after which everything works fine until it happens again after a few moments.
Specs:
   OS: Ubuntu 24.04
   CPU: Intel i7-12700 x20
   RAM: 16 GB DDR5
   GPU: Nvidia GeForce RTX 3060
   SSD: brand new Samsung T9 Portable SSD 2TB
   Motherboard: Dell 0R6PCT version A02
   BIOS: version 1.10.0
I am using 3 partitions: /media (ext4) /boot/efi (fat32) / (ext4))
After restarting the system who knows how many times, I finally downloaded 1 game onto my ssd despite it being 5-10 gb at a time. Yet installing other games does the same thing again.
I have used a few tools to check for errors around the system, to which i only found what seemed like my motherboard firmware being an older version. Whenever the SSD fails, however the error is "input/output".
I wouldn’t even know how to fix the issue if I could actually identify it. All I know is that during large data downloads to the SSD, it seems to go wrong somewhere during the process and ruin the entire OS until next reboot.
For extra clarification, the system worked fine before with and old HDD running Ubuntu as well. It downloaded and ran Steam games with no issues other than the fact that it was from 2014 and just slow.

Can you transfer equally-large amounts of other data to/from the SSD without error?

Hello, no I cannot. In fact I left it on for a few hours and it repeated the same process — all apps become unavailable. It seems that at some point during the system running, it loses access to the ssd. Even the terminal doesn’t work

An "input/output" error typically means a hardware fault with the storage device. Ubuntu cannot fix hardware faults.
